# caffe SqueezeNet: why phase commented?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to use caffe SqueezeNet. There are 2 versions (SqueezeNet_v1.0 and SqueezeNet_v1.1). I notice in SqueezeNet_v1.1/train_val.prototxt ([link](https://github.com/DeepScale/SqueezeNet/blob/master/SqueezeNet_v1.1/train_val.prototxt)) for layers "loss" and "accuracy" phase part is commented:

```
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "pool10"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
  #include {
  #  phase: TRAIN
  #}
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "pool10"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  #include {
  #  phase: TEST
  #}
}
```

Can someone please explain why? (it is not the case for another version i.e. SqueezeNet_v1.0 [link](https://github.com/DeepScale/SqueezeNet/blob/master/SqueezeNet_v1.0/train_val.prototxt))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By commenting the phase specification, you obtain accuracy and loss values both during training and test time.

Differently from the SqueezeNet_v1.0 version, the comments allow to see the accuracy on the training set (actually for the current training batch) and the total loss on the test/validation set which may be useful to control if your network is overfitting.